# TexStudio Menu is not fully visible

Tags: texstudio, ubuntu

I have installed Live Tex full in Ubuntu 12.04 with which Texstudio 2.7.0 is installed. However, there is no visible icon on the menu bars. They exist on the task bar and are clickable, but there is no visible graphics in them.

Please look at the following image:
[image]

You can only see left, center, and right alignment icons in the left and few list on the tool box menu.

Any help to sort it out?

Comment: I suggest you to install the newest version from here http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Sure, thanks. I will let you know the update.

Comment: If the most recent version does not work either, check if the qsvgicon library is installed.

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/400975/some-icons-symbols-in-texstudio-are-missing) (based on [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/831/)) might help: close TXS, run `sudo apt-get install libqt4-svg` and restart.

Comment: @henry that should be an answer

Comment: For openSUSE folks, the package is `libQt5Svg5`.

Comment: I have the same problem with Lubuntu and Texmaker. Does anyone know the solution in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue myself once. Googling led to [my own question on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400975/some-icons-symbols-in-texstudio-are-missing) and ultimately yielded:

1. close TXS
2. run `sudo apt-get install libqt4-svg`
3. restart TXS