# TeXstudio on Ubuntu 14.04: some shortcuts are not working, when some others do

Tags: texstudio

*I'm using `TeXstudio 2.10.8` (that was compiled with `Qt 5.2.1 R`), running on `Ubuntu 14.04`.*

---

**Issue:** Some default shortcuts of TXS (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, etc.) are working, when some others (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, etc.) don't.
How to fix this?

I have found two related tickets in the sourceForge repo ([#1467 Shortcuts does not work after upgrade to 2.10](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1467/) and [#1495 Keyboard shortcut for segment preview doesn't work](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1495/) ). However, the suggested solution is to wait for a newer (relative to the date of the post) release (that is `TXS 2.10.4`) since there was a bug due to `Qt 5.5`. But the version I'm using (`2.10.8`) is newer (and the most up-to-date public release as far as I can tell)...

Comment: I'm not really sure if there's anything we can do here, it sounds like a bug. (Bug reports are also generally considered off-topic.) Have you reported it at SourceForge?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you're right, I think it's a bug report. Should I then delete my question? (I've just posted a ticket on SourceForge.)

Comment: Either that, or you can add a link to the bug report and we can close the question.

Comment: [#1732 Some shortcuts are not working, when some others do](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1732/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report (reported at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1732/).

Comment: There was actually no bug: just `*tfm` I should have read (-; I thus posted my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained on [TXS webpage](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/index.html#download):

> For `Ubuntu 14.04` use Qt4 Version.

Thus, I stored my personnal settings (own shortcuts, etc.) stored in `~/.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini` and made a fresh install using the right version.

```
sudo apt-get remove texstudio
sudo apt-get install texstudio-qt4
```

Comment: I had the same problem - non-working shortcuts - in Ubuntu 16.04. I switched to the Qt4 version, and now the shortcuts are working, but there are other problems - the tools in the toolbar are invisible (I can click them, but I do not see them).

Comment: Henry's comment here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185760/texstudio-menu-is-not-fully-visible solved the problem: close TXS, run sudo apt-get install libqt4-svg and restart.