# Texmaker; some shortcuts don't work

Tags: texmaker, shortcut

For example, this shortcut on Texmaker 4.4.1-1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work: `CTRL+F`.
Did I miss something?
Because it's present in the keyboard shortcut list in the configuration options.

Some other listed shortcuts doesn't work either like `CTRL+G` or even the `F1` shortcut to fast compile a document.

Comment: [The same happens with TeXstudio](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302945/64454) (which is a fork of TeXmaker). The reason was an incompatibility with `Qt5`: installing the `Qt4` version solved the problem. As you can see on the [download page](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download_fr.html#linux), the `Ubuntu 16.04` version uses `Qt5`. So I'd suggest (solution not tested) to install the version developed for `Ubuntu 15.10` (or give a try to TeXstudio, it's worth it imho `(-;` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug due to Qt5. Workaround:

```
sudo apt remove appmenu-qt5
```

Comment: Any references?

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.10 does not work.

Comment: This action seem to cause some problem to me: at starting sometime mouse pointer will disappear. To the best of my knowledge the cause is due by removing the package appmenu-qt5
The best solution in my opinion is here http://askubuntu.com/a/786673/238973

Answer (score 0):

Create an alias in the `.bashrc` or create the file `~/.bash_aliases` and define the alias:

`alias texmaker='env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= texmaker'`

save it, exit and source it. From the home directory, do:

`$. .bashrc`

`$. .bash_aliases`

Done. Now opening Texmaker from the terminal will work perfectly.